# one to one video chat flash tutorial

Tags: flash, videochat

I am building a web app for online interview. I need to implement a one to one video chat in it. I am a noob in flash and video side. Can any one point to some good tutorials.

NOTE: I am working on a **linux** platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using red5 media server. It has some built in chat options and other sample apps are freely available.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good working example in [Wowza Media Server](http://www.wowza.com/) installation pack. Download Linux version and look in examples folder. This chat can be runned with other mediaservers too.